# dose tune of the kernel parameters can help to decrease the queue of CPU ( low cpu load average )

Tags: linux, cpu, performance, kernel, uptime

We have a machine with 32 CPU.

For now the results from **uptime** ( load average )

```
for 1 min -  23
for 5 min -  21
for 15 min - 20
```

We notice when the values are small, like ~3-8, 
the application works well, but when load average is high, like 20-30,
then we get poor results from the application side.

Can we improve results and decrease the CPU load average by tuning the kernel parameters, or any other parameter, in the Linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While CPU workload of course contributes to the load average, I am quite sure your application is not CPU bound, but I/O bound: Take a look at the `wait` values when running `top -d1`.

If (as I suspect) you get significant wait times, you are overloading your I/O subsystem? Are you maybe still using / spinning rust for a Database?

If it is indeed your storage subsystem, experience tells us, that while some careful tuning may help reduce waits (and thus load average), a value in the 20s range might just mean you are asking too much from your storage hardware.

Comment: we have hadoop cluster ( HDFS nodes ) , and I see that THP is enables when hadoop recommended to disabled , do you think this is the problem ?